# Per request variables in a node module? (express view helpers)

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am working on this project https://github.com/tanema/express-helpers that I forked fixed up and added new functionality to.

What I want to do it, instead of having to use form_tag_end() or even end_tag('tagname') I would just like to use a end() method. For this to work I need some sort of stack implementation for when a start tag is issued push onto the stack ect. I cannot just make a variable in the module called tagStack and just use that because it would create a race condition where the module is being used at the same time by two requests and the stack order gets messed up.

I was thinking if there was some way to have access to the request variable I would just store it in that and delete the variable if empty but I can't figure out how to do that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your variable within a closure; it will be available within the scope of the instance, but not outside the instantiation of the functions, and will be garbage collected when the specific instances go out of scope.

Comment: hmmm yeah that is a good idea I will have to think about how to do that to facilitate what I need but I think if anything this is the only route to go. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help; I'm just getting going on node.js myself, but the scoping and closures seem to be the key.